# Lebesgue measurable with two periods

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am trying to prove that a Lebesgue Measurable function with two periods $a $ and $b$ such that $b/a $ is irrational must ne constant almost everywhere....
I really dont know what to do, it says that I need to use Fourier series... can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: You can assume, witthout much loss of generality, that $2\pi$ is a period of your function. Take thte Fourier transform of your function. What does the periodicity tell you about the transform?

Comment: Is the function integrable?